# Deploy Google Cloud Function from Cloud Function

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

**Solved/invalid - see below**

I'm trying to deploy a Google Cloud Function from a Google Cloud Function on demand.

However, whatever I try, I get a 403 Forbidden:

HttpError 403 when requesting https://cloudfunctions.googleapis.com/v1/projects/MY_PROJECT/locations/MY_REGION/functions?alt=json returned "The caller does not have permission"

I ended up granting the cloud function service account Project Owner role to make sure it can do anything, yet still I get the same error.

Is this limited intentionally (for example to avoid fork bombs or something) or am I doing something wrong?

Has anyone been able to make this work?

For the record: I ran the same (Python) function locally with Flask using my own account and then it will deploy the new cloud function perfectly, so the code itself seems to be ok.

**Update**

Code snippet of how I'm trying to deploy the cloud function:

```
cf_client = discovery.build('cloudfunctions', 'v1')

location = "projects/{MYPROJECT}/locations/europe-west1"

request = {
    "name": "projects/{MYPROJECT}/locations/europe-west1/functions/hopper--2376cd24d318cd2d42f000f4f1c31a8f", 
    "description": "Hopper hopper--2376cd24d318cd2d42f000f4f1c31a8f", 
    "entryPoint": "pubsub_trigger", 
    "runtime": "python37", 
    "availableMemoryMb": 256, 
    "timeout": "60s", 
    "sourceArchiveUrl": "gs://staging.{MYPROJECT}.appspot.com/deployment/hopper.zip", 
    "eventTrigger": {
        "eventType": "providers/cloud.pubsub/eventTypes/topic.publish",
        "resource": "projects/{MYPROJECT}/topics/hopper-test-input"
    },
    "environmentVariables": {
        "HOPPER_ID": "hopper--2376cd24d318cd2d42f000f4f1c31a8f"
    }
}

response = cf_client.projects() \
    .locations() \
    .functions() \
    .create(location=location, body=req) \
    .execute()
```

**Update**

I feel like such an idiot... it turns out that for some reason I deployed the master function in a different project then the project I gave permissions on. No wonder it didn't work.

Comment: The Cloud Functions service account isn't used at runtime, only during management.  The App Engine default service account is used at runtime.  Or, you can configure and bring your own service account to authenticate and call other APIs.

Comment: Do you mind updating your question with the code?

Comment: @DougStevenson the default Cloud Functions service account seems to be the App Engine Service account -> <myproject>@appspot.gserviceaccount.com

I gave project owner role to this account and still it refuses to deploy the cloud function.

I set up a new service account to use for the cloud function. This seems to be 'alpha' functionality - in the web console it isn't availabe and on the command line I have to use 'gcloud alpha functions deploy ...' to get it to accept the --service-account parameter. The result is a CF that still runs as the default account, but isn't visible anywhere.

Comment: @NicksonThanda I can't completely share the code, and I don't think it really matters. I can share the REST request made by the master Cloud Function when attempting to deploy a new Cloud Function. I'll update in a bit.

Comment: Never mind, it turns out I messed up by launching the cloud function in a different project then it was supposed to be launched in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer should be: check that everything is indeed running how/where you expect it to be. Everything was configured correctly and deploying a CF in a CF is not a problem. The project was incorrect, due to a different default project being set on the gcloud utility.